# UPDATE with multiple SET-WHERE pairs

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding SQL syntax and whether or not a particular action is possible in a single query. Consider the following example:

Let's say we have a Recipe table. Every recipe has 5 ingredients listed under columns ingredient1, ingredient2, etc. Let's also say that suddenly sugar is determined to be unhealthy for you and every Recipe must replace 'sugar' with 'artificial sweetener' in every ingredient column where it exists. The problem I've run into is that there is no Ingredient table, thus every ingredient is listed literally under one of five columns rather than reference something like an ingredient ID.

How can I write the following (pseudo) query, if possible?

```
UPDATE Recipe 
    (SET ingredient1 = 'artificial sweetener' WHERE ingredient1 = 'sugar') OR
    (SET ingredient2 = 'artificial sweetener' WHERE ingredient2 = 'sugar') OR
    (SET ingredient3 = 'artificial sweetener' WHERE ingredient3 = 'sugar') OR
    (SET ingredient4 = 'artificial sweetener' WHERE ingredient4 = 'sugar') OR
    (SET ingredient5 = 'artificial sweetener' WHERE ingredient5 = 'sugar')
```

I have found multiple articles online about setting a column to a certain value based on its current value, but not for only setting (specific) columns that contain a value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The required SQL DML should be very simple e.g. `UPDATE Recipe SET ingredient = 'sugar' WHERE ingredient = 'artificial sweetener';` Whenever you find yourself wondering why something that should be so simple ends up being hard to write, suspect bad SQL DDL. The unit of work in SQL is the row, whereas you are having to do a lot of work enumerating columns. Consider fixing the SQL DDL to make the simple SQL DML work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CASE expression will dictate whether each of the five columns need to be modified. Use a WHERE clause to filter out any rows that don't require modification:

```
UPDATE Recipe
SET ingredient1 = CASE WHEN ( ingredient1 = 'sugar' )  
    THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient1 END ,
SET ingredient2 = CASE WHEN ( ingredient2 = 'sugar' )  
    THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient2 END ,
SET ingredient3 = CASE WHEN ( ingredient3 = 'sugar' )  
    THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient3 END ,
SET ingredient4 = CASE WHEN ( ingredient4 = 'sugar' )  
    THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient4 END ,
SET ingredient5 = CASE WHEN ( ingredient5 = 'sugar' )  
    THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient5 END
WHERE 'sugar' IN 
  ( ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3, ingredient4, ingredient5 )
;
```

Answer (score 6):

I'll answer your question with the "not what you want to hear" answer.  You've designed your database incorrectly.

You should have the structure:

```
Recipe
RecipeID, other recipe information

Ingredient
IngredientID, RecipeID, Ingredient, Measurement...
```

Ideally, actually, you'd probably have `Ingredient` as a lookup table and have `RecipeIngredient` as a joining table with the measurement information and `IngredientID`, but the above would still be significantly better than what you have.

Then your update would be:

```
update Ingredient 
    set Ingredient='artificial sweetener' 
    where Ingredient='sugar'
```

Comment: I agree 100%. Unfortunately, the databases I'm working in right now do not utilize foreign keys in any way :(

Comment: Agreed. A repeating group implemented as neighboring columns instead of as a child table violates first normal form.

Comment: @ggrigery You'll get nothing but grief and horrible work-arounds if you have to work with a poorly structured database.  If the database software doesn't allow you to link tables together like that, then you're probably using a spreadsheet.  If it's because someone else has imposed the database strucutre on you, go back and tell them to fix it.  You'll save time, effort, and pain in the long run.

Comment: @Kendrick Again, I'm of the same opinion. I'm trying to solve a corner case problem very quickly. My question wasn't "what's wrong with this scenario?", it was a very specific syntax-related issue. Furthermore, I'm not working in a database regarding recipes; I merely thought of a scenario that would quickly convey a problem similar to mine. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Considering redesigning your database, your current design is not very friendly..
Anyway the answer you're looking for is to use a case-when update clause;

```
UPDATE tablename
SET 
INGREDIENT1 = CASE WHEN INGREDIENT1='SUGAR' THEN 'ARTIFICIAL SWEETENER' ELSE INGREDIENT1    END,
INGREDIENT2 = CASE WHEN INGREDIENT2='SUGAR' THEN 'ARTIFICIAL SWEETENER' ELSE INGREDIENT2 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
UPDATE Recipe SET 
       ingredient1 = if(ingredient1 = 'sugar', 'artificial sweetener', ingredient1),
       ingredient2 = if(ingredient2 = 'sugar', 'artificial sweetener', ingredient2),
       ..etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is somewhat portable:

```
UPDATE Recipe
SET ingredient1 = CASE ingredient1 WHEN 'sugar' THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient1 END,
SET ingredient2 = CASE ingredient2 WHEN 'sugar' THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient2 END,
SET ingredient3 = CASE ingredient3 WHEN 'sugar' THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient3 END,
SET ingredient4 = CASE ingredient4 WHEN 'sugar' THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient4 END,
SET ingredient5 = CASE ingredient5 WHEN 'sugar' THEN 'artificial sweetener' ELSE ingredient5 END
WHERE ingredient1 = 'sugar'
    OR ingredient2 = 'sugar'
    OR ingredient3 = 'sugar'
    OR ingredient4 = 'sugar'
    OR ingredient5 = 'sugar'
```

Note that this technically updates all these columns regardless of the current value, as long as there is any sugar in the recipe.  That is a consequence of using a single `UPDATE` statement and this schema.  Query optimizers typically think in terms of whole rows and columns, not of individual values.